# How to write a selector for an element with a locator which is having a $ sign?

Tags: android, python, xpath, appium

I am trying to automate Alarm app on mobile with Appium and Python.
I need to click on "10" on a clock as shown below.
But the class for it's locator is,

```
android.widget.RadialTimePickerView$RadialPickerTouchHelper
```

Therefore, my XPath is not valid.

```
hr = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.RadialTimePickerView$RadialPickerTouchHelper[contains(@index, "9")]').click()
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVIka.png)

Comment: You may use the xpath with startsWith() function or use textContains() or textStartsWith() to avoid $ sign and take some part of the class name to identify the element.

Comment: @Sandeep - Thanks a lot. I used starts-with() function. I solved my issue.